# JavaScript elements gets appended more that once

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'm creating a web app using Django and one of its web pages allows the user to comment under others' posts. Once a user comments, I'm using Javascript to add the comment to the database and display it among the other comments in a div called "comment_list".
When I comment under a post for the first time, the comment is appended properly, only once. But when I comment for the second time, without refreshing the page, it gets appended twice. It gets appended thrice for the 3rd time and 4 times 4th the time and so on.

This is my HTML code

```
<button class="btn btn-dark" id="comment_{{post.id}}" onclick="comment('{{ post.id }}')" >Comment</button>
                <hr id="line1_{{post.id}}" style="display: none;">
                <textarea class="form-control mb-2" id="comment_box_{{post.id}}" name="comment" style="display:none;" required></textarea>
                <button id="comment_button_{{post.id}}" class="btn btn-dark" style="display:none;">Comment</button></br>

                <hr id="line2">
                <div id="comment_list_{{post.id}}">
                    {%for comment in comments%}
                        {%if comment in post.comments.all%}
                        <div>
                            <p style="margin-left: 1cm;">{{comment.user}} - {{comment.content}}</p>
                        </div>
                        {%endif%}
                    {%endfor%}
                </div>
```

This is the Javascript function

```
    function comment(id) {
    document.querySelector(`#comment_box_${id}`).style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector(`#comment_button_${id}`).style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector(`#line1_${id}`).style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector(`#comment_${id}`).style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector(`#comment_box_${id}`).value=""
    
    document.querySelector(`#comment_button_${id}`).addEventListener('click', () => {
        fetch('/comment/' + id, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                post: document.querySelector(`#comment_box_${id}`).value
            })
          })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((res) =>{
            
            var com = document.createElement('div');
            com.innerHTML = `<p style="margin-left: 1cm;">${res.user} - ${res.content}</p> `
            document.getElementById(`comment_list_${id}`).appendChild(com);
    
            document.querySelector(`#comment_box_${id}`).style.display = 'none';
            document.querySelector(`#comment_button_${id}`).style.display = 'none';
            document.querySelector(`#line1_${id}`).style.display = 'none';
            document.querySelector(`#comment_${id}`).style.display = 'initial';
            document.querySelector(`#comment_box_${id}`).value=""

          })  
    });
}
```

And this is the Python function

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required(login_url='login')
def comment(request, post_id):
    comment=Comment()
    if request.method == "PUT":
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        if data.get("post") is not None:    
            comment.content = data["post"]
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.save()
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
            post.comments.add(comment)
            post.save
        return JsonResponse({'user': request.user.username, 'content': data["post"], "status": 201})
```

I tried removing the event listener after the action is over and clearing the variable "com" but none of them worked. How can I fix this bug?

Comment: When you use the console to inspect the ajax(fetch) request what do you observe about the response data?? Is there repetition in that data?

Comment: yes there's a repetition

Comment: which suggests multiple entries in the db

Comment: yes, it gets appended to the database multiple times as well